# Passing parameter to partial view - Rails 4/postgresql/json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Deal model with a column/attribute called 'deal_info' which is a json column.

It looks like this for example

```
deal1.deal_info = [ { "modal_id": "4", "text1":"lorem" }, 
          { "modal_id": "6", "video2":"yonak" },
          { "modal_id": "9", "video2":"boom" } ] 
deal2.deal_info = [ { "modal_id": "10", "text1":"lorem" }, 
          { "modal_id": "11", "video2":"yonak" },
          { "modal_id": "11", "image4":"boom" } ]
```

**On my view deal.html.erb, i have:**

```
<%= for deal_nb in 0..@deal.number_of_deals do %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myInfoModal<%= modal_nb %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- render the right modal type -->
    <%= render "layouts/modal_type_partials/mt#{ @deal.deal_info[deal_nb]['modal_id'] }", parameter_i_want_to_pass: deal_nb  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Above, as you see above, I'd like to pass for each iteration of the loop inside parameter_i_want_to_pass the number of the iteration loop (2nd iteration would be parameter_i_want_to_pass= 2 for example).

**On the partial I have:**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">this is mt4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      this is the text: <%= @deal.deal_info[parameter_i_want_to_pass]['text1'] %> 

    </div>
  </div>
```

I get the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (on line "this is the text: <%= @deal.deal_info[parameter_i_want_to_pass]")
```

Actually I even tried to detect more easily the bug by just passing a set number instead of the variable 'deal_nb'

```
<%= render "layouts/modal_type_partials/mt#{ @deal.deal_info[deal_nb]['modal_id'] }", parameter_i_want_to_pass: 2  %>
```

But I still get exactly the same error.

**EDIT**

To help identify the problem, if I replace inside the partial view, @deal.deal_info[parameter_i_want_to_pass]['text1'] by @deal.deal_info[2]['text1'], then it works so the problem must really be that the partial view does not want to receive the number I set inside the deal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">this is mt4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          this is the text: <%= @deal.deal_info[2]['text1'] %> 

        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**EDIT 2**
Just to update the question, I managed to solve a part of the problem. i used the method to_i to transform the string in a number

So the code above now works, it pass the information (parameter_i_want_to_pass =2) to the partial view. I checked it.

```
<%= render "layouts/modal_type_partials/mt#{ @deal.deal_info[deal_nb]['modal_id'] }", parameter_i_want_to_pass: 2  %>
```

But the remaining problem, is how to not set it to 2 but to pass the number of the iteration loop

```
<%= for deal_nb in 0..@deal.number_of_deals do %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="myInfoModal<%= modal_nb %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <!-- render the right modal type -->
        <%= render "layouts/modal_type_partials/mt#{ @deal.deal_info[deal_nb]['modal_id'] }", parameter_i_want_to_pass: deal_nb  %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

Here I run into an Error

```
undefined local variable or method `modal_number'
```

Comment: What line in what file is the above error message referring to? I can't see in the code you've posted, where you're using the modal_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable names are a little confusing, but I think this is what you're trying to do. I am using the `each_with_index` method to loop through each modal inside of the `deal`'s `deal_info`. Then I use the `locals: { }` argument for `render partial:` in order to pass variables to the partial. The partial then refers to these variables like they are defined locally. The partial doesn't even really end up needing the `index` variable, but I showed how you would pass it anyway.

**View**

```
<% @deal.deal_info.each_with_index do |modal, index| %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myInfoModal<%= index %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- render the right modal type -->
    <%= render partial: "layouts/modal_type_partials/mt#{ modal['modal_id'] }", locals: { modal: modal, index: index }  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Partial**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">this is mt4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      this is the text: <%= modal['text1'] %> 
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

Comment: thanks for your help, will check it now. seems very clever and factorized/clean: )

Answer (score 0):

```
deal1.deal_info = [ { "modal_id": "4", "text1":"lorem" }, 
      { "modal_id": "6", "video2":"yonak" },
      { "modal_id": "9", "video2":"boom" } ]
```

is not valid ruby code. You need to parse the json string:

```
require 'json'

deal1.deal_info = JSON.parse('[
  { "modal_id": "4", "text1":"lorem" },
  { "modal_id": "6", "video2":"yonak" },
  { "modal_id": "9", "video2":"boom" }
]')
```

This will convert it into an array of hashes:

```
[{"modal_id"=>"4", "text1"=>"lorem"}, {"modal_id"=>"6", "video2"=>"yonak"}, {"modal_id"=>"9", "video2"=>"boom"}]
```